# Oracle select query on condition

Tags: oracle, select, conditional-statements

Using python to query Oracle database and trying to select data from a table if a condition is met. So something like this:

Data in Table:

```
ID  | Name
123 | F100
124 | F200
125 | F100
126 | F300
127 | F100
```

So I want to select all of the data that has the Name 'F100' and pull back the ID and Name.

Comment: Are you asking how to select in python? or about the SQL statement to achieve this?

Comment: sorry the SQL statement and have something like:

select ID from Table
where ID (select from Table where Name = 'F100'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement would just be

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE name = 'F100'
```